# error in list appened function

Tags: c++, linked-list

ive been getting errors in both visual studio and g++ i tried gdb but did not get anything useful from it

visual studio = Unhandled exception at 0x00CD464F in array2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.

gdb gave =Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
370x000000010040118f in list::append (this=0x23aa80, x=6) at main.cpp:61

```
      #include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
// "arraylist.h"
#include <new>
//#include "myList.h"
using namespace std;


struct node{
    int data;
    node* next;
};
struct list{
    node* head;
    void append(int x);
};
int main()
{
    list L;
    L.append(6);
    node* cur = L.head;
    while (cur->next != 0)
    {
        std::cout << cur->data << std::endl;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

void list::append(int x)
{
    node* tmp = new node;
    node* cur = head;
    tmp->data = x;
    tmp->next;
    if (cur->data == 0)
    {
        head = tmp;
    }

    else{
        while (cur->next != 0)
        {
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        cur->next = tmp;

    }


}
```

Comment: You did get useful information.  gdb said you had a segfault at line 61 of main.cpp.  Which line is that?

Comment: It's likely here: `    if (cur->data == 0)`

Comment: `tmp->next;` Hmmm...... Enable warnings. Your compiler will tell you something like "code has no effect".

Comment: @bumblebee -- You said you used Visual Studio -- if you really did, then the error would have been picked up by the VS debugger in no time flat (just hit F5 and you would see right away the program fails).  The "head" is not initialized but you are setting "cur" to this uninitialized value.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of hints:

1. You are not initialising `L.head` (thanks @Alan Stokes).
2. You are not initializing `tmp->next`.
3. `cur->data == 0` is not the right way to check whether the list is empty.

Comment: Also you're not initialising `L.head`.

Comment: Can't upvote right now, most probably right!

Comment: It really is full of headscratchers... But these should be all potential crashers. --- I really like the `tmp->next` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invalid because data member head of the list is not initialized when an object of the list is created

```
struct list{
    node* head;
    void append(int x);
};
int main()
{
    list L;  // <== head is not initialized.
```

You could write for example

```
    list L = { 0 };
```

Or

```
struct list{
    node* head = 0;
    void append(int x);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

in

```
if (cur->data == 0)
{
    head = tmp;
}
```

you are trying to access the head of the newly created `list` object, which means you are using an uninitialized pointer. This means that whenever you dereference it, you are accessing an undetermined part of the memory, in this case a part you are not suppose to access(which cause the access violation error). I suggest setting `head` with `NULL` in a struct constructor, and checking if head is `NULL` in every method that tries to access it (in this case,`list::append(int)`).

```
list::list(){
   head = NULL;
}
```

This empty constructor is called implicitly when you use `list L;`